# How do I disable GridFS MD5 calculation in Spring Boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, gridfs

Now that the `md5` attribute of GridFS files collection is obsolete, drivers are not required to compute it, so I'd like to disable it to spare a few milliseconds maybe...

The MongoDB Java driver does provide an option `disableMD5` in `GridFSBucketImpl`, but since I'm using Spring Boot's `GridFsTemplate` (spring-data-mongodb 2.1.2.RELEASE) I don't have direct access to it. `GridFsTemplate` has a method `getGridFs()` that returns a `GridFSBucket` configured for the current database and bucket name, but unfortunately this method is private so I can't override it.

So what are my options? Do I have to override all of `GridFsTemplate`? Did I miss a simple setting somewhere? Should I submit a feature request to Spring?

**Update**
Obviously `GridFsTemplate` is not meant to be extended (though all it would take is `getGridFs` and a couple fields to be protected) so I ended up creating my own `CustomGridFsTemplate`, which is an almost exact copy of `GridFsTemplate` except that I call `GridFSBucket.withDisableMD5(true)` in `getGridFs`.

I'm not very happy with that, but it works and I don't see a better option for now.

**Update 2**
I have submitted a Spring feature request, please vote for it! https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no better way. Looks like you filed [a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2165) to extend `GridFsTemplate` to allow the customizations.